# convert AMPM to datetime 24 hour

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I'm trying to convert 01-31-2017 09:01 AM into 24 hour datetime ( i have AM PM in my values), but it keep giving me 1969-12-31 16:00:00

Here's what I've done:

```
$old_date = strtotime("01-31-2017 09:01 AM");
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $old_date);
```

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the format of the string you better use the [`date_create_from_format` function](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$s = '01-31-2017 09:01 AM';
$date = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y h:i A', $s);
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

When you use the `strtotime` you let the php parse the string, and it might lead to a result you are not looking for (for example - `01-02-2017` - is it jan 2nd or feb 1st?).